# Kuberetes unusual phenomenon： Old ReplicaSet and Old pods are still alive with New ReplicaSet and New pods when rolling upgrade

Tags: kubernetes

When I use Kubernetes restful api to do rolling-upgrade, after upgrade, New ReplicaSet is created, New pods are running and get the desire replicas. But at the same time, Old ReplicaSet and Old pods were still running. Deployment's replicas are 3, When I check data in `etcd`, New ReplicaSet's replicas is 3, Old ReplicaSet's replicas is 2, I can't find any error information in controller manager log.

Another question: Why kubectl do not use restful api to do rolling-update? kubectl do rolling-upgrade [in this way](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubectl/rolling_updater.go)

My Code:

```
cli := rdc.k8sClients
dp, err := cli.Extensions().Deployments(namespace).Get(deployment)
if err != nil {
    return
}

curImage := dp.Spec.Template.Spec.Containers[0].Image

ds := new(extensions.DeploymentStrategy)
ds.Type = extensions.RollingUpdateDeploymentStrategyType
ds.RollingUpdate = new(extensions.RollingUpdateDeployment)
ds.RollingUpdate.MaxUnavailable = intstr.FromInt(int(ROLLING_MAXUNAVAILABLE))
ds.RollingUpdate.MaxSurge = intstr.FromInt(int(ROLLING_MAXSURGE))

_, err = cli.Extensions().Deployments(namespace).Update(dp)
```

Comment: What commands are you using to do the rolling upgrade? What is the output from `kubectl describe rs <old ReplicaSet>/<new ReplicaSet>`?

Comment: I use restful api to do rolling upgrade: rclient.Extensions().Deployments(namespace).Update(deployment)

Comment: To trigger a rolling update of a Deployment, one needs to update Deployment's `.spec.template`. In your code, I didn't see the Deployment's template being updated.

Comment: I have the same unusual phenomenon with you. I use command 'kubectl replace -f ***.yaml'. But I found a strange thing that the old ReplicaSet will lose the field 'ownerReferences'. I think this field will be used to connect the old ReplicaSet and the new ReplicaSet. Scale the old pod down and the new pod up. But I don't know why the field 'ownerReferences' lost. Can this message help you?  Or you have already resolved the issue?